# Sources for an object's (and others) perspective when moving near the speed of light

Tags: time-dilation

Imagine that there's a stable elementary particle at 99.9999% the speed of light. This would mean that to a stationary object it would look like it's extremely small. Supposedly from the particle's perspective the stationary object would be smaller, have slower time, and also something else I think I'm forgetting. Where can I find sources for this? English is not my first language so sorry if I make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine that there's a stable elementary particle at $99.9999 \%$ the speed of light.

First, as you are concern with the length contraction. Let's not talk of particles that have no dimensions. Let's better think of rod.

---

> This would mean that to a stationary object it would look like it's extremely small.

Yes! If the rod is moving then for the stationary observer the length of the rod will get contracted. The observer on the rod will observe stationary objects to be contracted. The length contraction is symmetrical this way.

---

As for time dilation, The reasoning would be similar.